# Changing size of UIWebView text

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, text-size

I'm trying to change text size in UIWebView, but I don't know how. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589177/how-to-increase-font-size-in-uiwebview); it provides a JavaScript based solution.