# Change font size of text displaying into uiWebView loaded from text file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have text file with some random text and i want to display it in webview with increased font,my question is can i change the font size. here is my code i have implemented.

```
NSString * myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:_urlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
self.webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this question
[how to increase font size in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589177/how-to-increase-font-size-in-uiwebview)
You could do it with a javascript command

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the exact structure of your html string and you would need to modify the html string to change the font and font size. Add/Modify html tags around required text in order to change font and/or font size.

Use `NSMutableString` instead of `NSString` and then modify your string according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by using html tags.

```
NSString *stringToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><center><font size=+5>%@</font></center></html>", myString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string to valid html string and then set font-family for html string:

```
NSString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                                "<head> \n"
                                "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                                "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                                "</style> \n"
                                "</head> \n"
                                "<body>%@</body> \n"
                                "</html>", @"HelveticaNeue", [NSNumber numberWithInt:kFieldFontSize], myString];
```

Comment: what does content men here ??

Comment: content is your `myString ` which u'll get from file. edited answer